# Dictionaries are not working, also I am getting 'KeyError: 0' error messages and I do not know what that means :/ (python by the way)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find out what is the best building to buy in Cookie Clicker at any time. Right now, I am having trouble with the last line. 'cost[number] = basecost[number]* 1.15**(amount-free)'. It says 'KeyError: 0', and I have no idea what that means so forgive me for the vague title. Also if you can tell me ways to optimize it, because I doubt copying and pasting dictionaries is a good way to go about this.

```
basecost = {
    
    "cursor" : 15,
    "grandma" : 100,
    "farm" : 1100,
    "mine" : 12000,
    "factory" : 130000,
    "bank" : 1400000,
    "temple" : 20000000,
    "wizardtower" : 330000000,
    "shipment" : 5100000000,
    "alchemylad" : 75000000000,
    "portal" : 1000000000000,
    "timemachine" : 14000000000000,
    "antimattercondenser" : 170000000000000,
    "prism" : 2100000000000000,
    "chancemaker" : 26000000000000000,
    "fractalengine" : 310000000000000000,
    "javascriptconsole" : 71000000000000000000

    }

cost = {

    "cursor" : None,
    "grandma" : None,
    "farm" : None,
    "mine" : None,
    "factory" : None,
    "bank" : None,
    "temple" : None,
    "wizardtower" : None,
    "shipment" : None,
    "alchemylad" : None,
    "portal" : None,
    "timemachine" : None,
    "antimattercondenser" : None,
    "prism" : None,
    "chancemaker" : None,
    "fractalengine" : None,
    "javascriptconsole" : None,
    
    }

basecps = {
    
    "cursor" : 0.1,
    "grandma" : 1,
    "farm" : 8,     
    "mine" : 47,
    "factory" : 260,
    "bank" : 1400,
    "temple" : 7800,
    "wizardtower" : 44000,
    "shipment" : 260000,
    "alchemylad" : 1600000,
    "portal" : 10000000,
    "timemachine" : 65000000,
    "antimattercondenser" : 430000000,
    "prism" : 2900000000,
    "chancemaker" : 21000000000,
    "fractalengine" : 150000000000,
    "javascriptconsole" : 1100000000000,

    }

buildingplural = [
    
    "Cursors",
    "Grandmas",
    "Farms",
    "Mines",
    "Factories",
    "Banks",
    "Temples",
    "Wizard Towers",
    "Shipments",
    "Alchemy Labs",
    "Portals",
    "Time Machines",
    "Antimatter Condensers",
    "Prisms",
    "Chancemakers",
    "Fractal Engines",
    "Javascript Consoles"

    ]


for number, item in enumerate(buildingplural):

    amount = int(input("How many "+ item +" do you have?"))
    free = int(input("How many "+ item +" did you get for free?"))

    cost[number] = basecost[number]*1.15**(amount-free)
```

Comment: why do you *think* that `cost[number]` should return anythign? There is no `int` keys in any of your dictionaries.

Comment: I remember that if you write 'list[0]' it is the first number in the list. Maybe I am thinking of another thing.

Comment: yes... you are thinking of a *list*. A dictionary is not a list... A dictionary maps keys to values, you access a value with a corresponding key. a list is a sequence of values, that you can access by position (i.e. integer index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error dues to you're trying to get the value of the the dict `basecost` element by a number and not by its key in the `for` loop and what you have to do is something like this:

```
for item in buildingplural:

    amount = int(input("How many "+ item +" do you have?"))
    free = int(input("How many "+ item +" did you get for free?"))
    key_dict = item.lower()[:-1] 
    cost[number] = basecost[key_dict]*1.15**(amount-free)
```

As you could see, you need to create a `key_dict` because `buildingplural` elements are the plural of the other `dicts` elements. Hope this can help you :)

About the second question and how to optimize the creations of the dicts, you can't do so much because the values of them are different and there's no any relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to enumerate the list here. Your keys are the items in the list.

```
for item in buildingplural:

    amount = int(input("How many "+ item +" do you have?"))
    free = int(input("How many "+ item +" did you get for free?"))

    cost[item] = basecost[item]*1.15**(amount-free)
```

Comment: The items in the buildingplural list are not the same items in the dictionary, they are just a way to avoid making loads of if statements. I guess I could make them the same word.

Answer (score 0):

cost[number] will not work since cost is a dictionary and not list.

You need to do something like below. This will create a new dict called 'newcost' and create a dictionary with keys from 'cost' dictionary and new derived values.

```
newcost = {}
for number, item in enumerate(buildingplural):
    amount = int(input("How many "+ item +" do you have?"))
    free = int(input("How many "+ item +" did you get for free?"))
    newcost.update({(list(cost.keys())[number]): list(basecost.values())[number]*1.15**(amount-free) })
```